# Call function from .js file in .js.erb file in Rails 7

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb, ruby-on-rails-7

So I am following this tutorial https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/lets-create-an-intermediate-level-ruby-on-rails-application-d7c6e997c63f/ and although many of the technologies used in it are deprecated or changed, I wanted to give it a try. I am in the part that tries to render a private pop-up conversation window.

When you click on another user's post, you can
[send them a message and start a new conversation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK4w6.png)

After you send a message,
[a pop-up conversation is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6Wf0.png)

The **problem ** is that even though the conversation window is added, it is minimized and i can't see its content.
[The conversation window's content is loaded inside the html as you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jClP6.png)

For the addition of a conversation window to the app, we use a .js.erb file inside the app/views/private/conversations folder called _open.js.erb .

The code for the _open.js.eb:

```
var conversation = $('body').find("[data-pconversation-id='" + 
                                "<%= @conversation.id %>" + 
                                "']");
var chat_windows_count = $('.conversation-window').length + 1;

if (conversation.length !== 1) {
  $('body').append("<%= j(render 'private/conversations/conversation',\
                                  conversation: @conversation,\
                                  user: current_user) %>");
  conversation = $('body').find("[data-conversation-id='" + 
                                "<%= @conversation.id %>" + 
                                "']");
}

// Toggle conversation window after its creation
$('.conversation-window:nth-of-type(' + chat_windows_count + ')\
   .conversation-heading').click();
// mark as seen by clicking it
setTimeout(function(){ 
  $('.conversation-window:nth-of-type(' + chat_windows_count + ')').click();
 }, 1000);
// focus textarea
$('.conversation-window:nth-of-type(' + chat_windows_count + ')\
   form\
   textarea').focus();

// repositions all conversation windows
positionChatWindows();
```

In the javascript directory i have create a file which will take care of the conversations’ windows visibility and positioning.

The file (app/javascript/conversations/position_and_visibility.js):

```
import "jquery"
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() { 
    console.log("hello from the other side");
    chat_windows_count = $('.conversation-window').length;
    // if the last visible chat window is not set and conversation windows exist
    // set the last_visible_chat_window variable
    if (gon.last_visible_chat_window == null && chat_windows_count > 0) {
        gon.last_visible_chat_window = chat_windows_count;
    }
    // if gon.hidden_chats doesn't exist, set its value
    if (gon.hidden_chats == null) {
        gon.hidden_chats = 0;
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', hideShowChatWindow);
    positionChatWindows();
    hideShowChatWindow();
});

function positionChatWindows() {
    chat_windows_count = $('.conversation-window').length;
    // if a new conversation window was added, 
    // set it as the last visible conversation window
    // so the hideShowChatWindow function can hide or show it, 
    // depending on the viewport's width
    if (gon.hidden_chats + gon.last_visible_chat_window !== chat_windows_count) {
        if (gon.hidden_chats == 0) {
            gon.last_visible_chat_window = chat_windows_count;
        }
    }

    // when a new chat window is added, position it to the most left of the list
    for (i = 0; i < chat_windows_count; i++ ) {
        var right_position = i * 410;
        var chat_window = i + 1;
        $('.conversation-window:nth-of-type(' + chat_window + ')')
            .css('right', '' + right_position + 'px');
    }
}

// Hides last conversation window whenever it is close to viewport's left side
function hideShowChatWindow() {
    // if there are no conversation windows, stop the function
    if ($('.conversation-window').length < 1) {
        return;
    }
    // get an offsset of the most left conversation window
    var offset = $('.conversation-window:nth-of-type(' + gon.last_visible_chat_window + ')').offset();
    // if the left offset of the conversation window is less than 50, 
    // hide this conversation window
    if (offset.left < 50 && gon.last_visible_chat_window !== 1) {
        $('.conversation-window:nth-of-type(' + gon.last_visible_chat_window + ')')
            .css('display', 'none');
        gon.hidden_chats++;
        gon.last_visible_chat_window--;
    }
    // if the offset of the most left conversation window is more than 550 
    // and there is a hidden conversation, show the hidden conversation
    if (offset.left > 550 && gon.hidden_chats !== 0) {
        gon.hidden_chats--;
        gon.last_visible_chat_window++;
        $('.conversation-window:nth-of-type(' + gon.last_visible_chat_window + ')')
            .css('display', 'initial');
    }
}
```

I would like to add that i am using importmaps
config/importmap.rb:

```
# Pin npm packages by running ./bin/importmap

pin "application",preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin "jquery", to: "jquery.min.js", preload: true
pin "jquery_ujs", to: "jquery_ujs.js", preload: true

pin "popper", to: 'popper.js', preload: true
pin "bootstrap", to: 'bootstrap.min.js', preload: true

pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/posts", under: "posts"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/conversations", under: "conversations"
pin "@rails/actioncable", to: "actioncable.esm.js"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/channels", under: "channels"
```

app/javascript/application.js:

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
import "conversations/position_and_visibility"
import "conversations/toggle_window"
import "conversations/conversation"
import "conversations/messages_infinite_scroll"

import "jquery"
import "jquery_ujs"

import "popper"
import "bootstrap"
import "channels"
```

and also it seems that the js file is imported
[image]

The desired output
[image]

If you'd like additional info, please let me know.